# Which libraries are needed for mapreduce on HBase?

Tags: maven, mapreduce, hbase, hadoop2

I have a very basic question! what libraries I need for MapReduce on HBase?
I know I must use TableMapper and I've got hadoop-client 2.2.0 and hbase-client 0.98.2 from maven but there's no TableMapper in API. 
Thank you.

Comment: could you share the minimal dependency needed to import TableMapper?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In addition to `hbase-client` dependency you need same version `hbase-server` dependency, this will also include the mapreduce libraries you need.
If you're using Maven, you need to add in your `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

(At the moment of writing last version is `1.1.2`)
Good luck!

Comment: thank you for the response, isn't it better to get hbase-hadoop2-compat only?

Comment: Just declaring dependency on hbase-hadoop2-compat is not enough - that package just holds specific glue between hbase and hadoop - not connected with map reduce.  For MapReduce you need the hbase-server dependency - that is where the TableMapper and TableMapReduceUtil are located.

Comment: Is it the following? `groupId:org.apache.hbase artifactId:hbase-server version:0.99.2` (simplified maven)

Answer (score 4):

before `hbase 2.0`,you need add the follow dependce in the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
<version>1.3.1</version>
```

after `hbase 2.0`,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-mapreduce</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0</version>
```